# Remove effect for first and last slide SwiperJS

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I've integrated swiper slide with coverflow effect, now I don't want the effect for first and last slide. can we remove the effect for only first and lst slide.???

Answer (score 0):

You can check your position and disable "swipe to prev" when you are in the first tab, and "swipe to next" when you are in the last one. Like this,

```
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            effect:'coverflow',
            pagination: '#progressbar',
            paginationType: 'progress',
            nextButton: '#next-button',
            prevButton: '#prev-button',
            spaceBetween: 30,

            onInit: function (swiper) {
                if (swiper.activeIndex == 0)    swiper.lockSwipeToPrev(); 
                if (swiper.isEnd)               swiper.lockSwipeToNext(); 
            },

            onSlideChangeStart: function (swiper) {
                if (swiper.activeIndex == 0)    swiper.lockSwipeToPrev(); 
                else                            swiper.unlockSwipeToPrev(); 

                if (swiper.isEnd)               swiper.lockSwipeToNext(); 
                else                            swiper.unlockSwipeToNext(); 
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the `slideShadows` property. If so, you can easily show/hide it, as following:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was fix hyperlink states via CSS like below sample and it's working fine.

```
.swiper-slide a {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next a {
    pointer-events: unset !important;
}
```